# Expect/TCL telnet proc does not wait for the prompt

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a Expect proc that sends command for telnet login and send commands. Inside the telnet proc I do a TFTP . The size of the file is 10MB. 
But the telent prompt does not wait until the prompt appears .It waits for the timeout period 
and comes off.

is there any way we can wait for the prompt in Expect .

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: tip for Expect development:  `exp_internal 1` shows you what Expect sees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tftp file transfer takes longer than Expect's default timeout (10 seconds) you will need to set a longer timeout first.  Eg. for a 60-second timeout, start your script with:

```
set timeout 60
```

For more detailed help you had better post your Expect script.