# Tcl expect error with spawning telnet: invalid command name

Tags: scripting, tcl, expect, telnet, mud

How do I send just a "return" to this telnet server:

```
got New York
spawn telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
Trying 35.160.169.47...
Connected to rainmaker.wunderground.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:invalid command name ""
    while executing
"[tutstack::connect "New York"]"
    (file "main.tcl" line 6)
```

code:

```
package provide weather  1.0
package require Tcl      8.5
package require Expect


namespace eval ::tutstack {
}

proc ::tutstack::connect {arg1} {
puts "got $arg1"
spawn telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
set telnet $spawn_id
expect -nocase "Press Return to continue:"
send  "$arg1"
}
```

main:

```
lappend auto_path /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet/api

package require weather 1.0


[tutstack::connect "New York"]
```

I've tried [variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) on `send  "\r"` without success.

Ultimately, would want the script to only [partially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_client) automate responses and leave the connection [open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1741137/262852).

expected result:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
Trying 35.160.169.47...
Connected to rainmaker.wunderground.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:

Press Return for menu
or enter 3 letter forecast city code--    

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:
```

Ideally, I'd like *some* responses automated but would ultimately want to enter text which is sent to the telnet server as well -- depending on the logic.  But for right now, just trying to script some responses.

see also:

[expect - telnet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50567300/262852)

Comment: what happened when you `send  "\r"`? any error message?

Comment: and could you elaborate a bit more what do you mean by *"partially automate responses and leave the connection open"*?

Comment: it shows `invalid command name` above and just exits, wheras it should then proceed to a menu.  I'll elaborate @pynexj

Comment: Remove the `[]` around `[tutstack::connect "New York"]` to get rid of the error message. Your proc is finishing and returning to main. You are then executing the returned empty string.

Comment: got it, thanks @meuh

Comment: that's why a [mcve] would help a lot. :)

Comment: fair enough, @pynexj -- I was perhaps a bit stuck on using a main script.

Comment: @meuh You should have written that up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks meuh:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ tclsh main.tcl 
got New York
spawn telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
Trying 35.160.169.47...
Connected to rainmaker.wunderground.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ cat main.tcl 
lappend auto_path /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet/api

package require weather 1.0


tutstack::connect "New York"
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ cat api/weather.tcl 
package provide weather  1.0
package require Tcl      8.5
package require Expect


namespace eval ::tutstack {
}

proc ::tutstack::connect {arg1} {
puts "got $arg1"
spawn telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
set telnet $spawn_id
expect -nocase "Press Return to continue:"
send  "$arg1"
}

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$
```